# Sonar Qube not taking code coverage into effect

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I am using Azure DevOps Build pipeline for my build process, which is integrated with Sonar Qube.

The Sonar Qube analysis contains the code smells, however, the code coverage is coming as 0.0.

The actual code coverage of the build is around 90% (as seen in the summary) but it's not getting reflected in the Sonar Qube report.

As per my initial analysis, the "Sonar Qube complete analysis step" is looking for TRX files in `D:\a\1\TestResults`, but from the "Run VSTest Cases" step I can see that the test result is being kept at `D:\a_temp\TR_6001850d-aa48-437b-be71-58d37fdcddc9\VssAdministrator_fv-az355_2019-03-18_15_16_27.trx`

Any ideas as to how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the build creates code coverage results? You need the VS Enterprise version or an other code coverage tool to create a report that SonarQube can use. See for more detailt the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770).

Comment: Yes the build created code coverage, and all projects have <DebugType>Full</DebugType>